# Manipulating an expression into another equivalent form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an expression (shown below) and I want to show that

$$(n+1)(n)(3n^2+11n+10) = (n)(n+1)(n-1)(3n+2) + \text{some other stuff}$$

How can I do this?

Comment: Simplify $n(n+1)(3n^2 + 11n + 10) - n(n+1)(n-1)(3n+2)$. That's the other stuff.

Comment: Just use the fact that $AB=AC+(AB-AC)$. Here the parenthesized expression is your other stuff.

Comment: That wasn't readily obvious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** compute explicitely $$(n-1)(3n+2)-3n^2+11n+10$$
to find what is the "some other stuffs".

But, if you just need to show that there exists "some other stuffs" such that
$$(n+1)(n)(3n^2+11n+10) = (n)(n+1)(n-1)(3n+2) + \text{some other stuff},$$
just set 
$$\text{some other stuffs}=(n+1)(n)(3n^2+11n+10) - (n)(n+1)(n-1)(3n+2)$$

Comment: Some comments: $(n)(n+1)[(3n^2+11n+10-(n-1)(3n+2)]= (n)(n+1)(\text{some other stuffs})$.

Comment: @DonLarynx yes, this is implicitly meant in the **Hint** but if you just need existence, you don't even need to see that there is a possible factorisation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the distributive property: if $ab = ac+ x$, then subtracting $ac$ from both sides gives
$$ab-ac=a(b-c)=x$$
In your case,
$$a=(n+1)(n),\qquad b=3n^2+11n+10,\qquad c=(n-1)(3n+2)=3n^2-n-2$$